# Ag Grid React col equals function gets undefined params

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using custom functional cellRenderer. I know that according to docs it can't reimplement the refresh function. It's totally fine, i don't need it. But i want to override the **equals** function - according to docs **equals** by default compares `(a,b)=>a===b` - this won't work for me cause i need a deepEqual.

So when something triggers refreshing  (like **applyTransaction**, **refreshCells**) my custom cell is not being refreshed.
I know for sure it's not because of the lack of the refresh method cause if i override **equals** like the following it will always rerender -   `equals: (a,b)=>false`

But i would prefer not to rerender cell any time - it has some relatively heavy calculations behind the scene. Checking for deepEquality would be, of course, more reasonable. The problem is that `(a,b)` params at **equals** are always undefined for some reason. (overriding it at **colDef**). Not attaching here code of my **cellRenderer** cause there's nothing that could help, just a function returning functional component and passing some cellParams data down to it. Any suggestions why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

it is solved with a value getter. In my case:

```
{
   ...column,
   equals: (a, b) => isEqual(a, b),
   valueGetter: (api) => {
                const id = api.data.id;
                return api.node.rowModel.nodeManager.allNodesMap[id].data
                    .mainRule?.condition?.treeFormat;
            },
   }
```